# Firebase getCurrentUser method explanation required

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can any one tell me that what does get Current User do?

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        //start profile activity
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile.class));
    }
```

I am confused on which user get Current User pick?

Answer (score 2):

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() returns the currently logged in user in firebase. The user which whith whom the credentials you made the login from your android emulator. If a user isn't signed in, getCurrentUser returns null.

Answer (score 2):

`firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is used get a `FirebaseUser` object, which contains information about the signed-in user.
If it returns null the user has not signed in else it will be redirected to Profile.class...(In your above code)